# Gradle blocked on :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: java, android, gradle, docker

Today I was working on my android app. I pushed a new commit and I was waiting for the notification of successful build, but nothing arrived. The build server is blocked on `:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug` and the server has 100% load on every cpu core. I tried also using jdk8 and jdk7 but nothing changed.

For `blocked` I mean that the last line of the logs are `:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug` and in debug mode:

> 16:43:31.127 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle]
>   Changing state to: STARTING 16:43:31.132 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process
>   started: command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'.
>   16:43:31.136 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle]
>   Changing state to: STARTED 16:43:31.136 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams
>   are handled... 16:43:31.136 [INFO]
>   [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started
>   process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java''

My build server use docker for running builds, maybe is something related to it, but i don't think so, because last week it worked like a charm, taking maximium 5min per build

Answer (score 0):

Try with "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart".

Comment: Server use always a new clean environment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and i was able to resolve it by enabling Proguard in the gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
}
```

More info on this can be found: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Supposedly the gradle was giving this error because the app excedes the 65K method references Limit.
More info: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#avoid

Hope this solves it for you!